# Displaying CDATA in XML with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cdata

Hey all I have a XML file where the "course_desc" element is copy/pasted value(the unit description with multiple paragraphs and formatting) from a website so I want to display it in CDATA and for it to retain it's original formatting.

```
<courses>
<course>
<course_desc>
  <![CDATA[
This course structure contains information about the units which comprise the course as well as the credit points required to successfully complete it.

Students must complete the programme outlined below. All semester enrolments are subject to unit availability and students must consult the Course Coordinator prior to enrolling.

WORK INTEGRATED LEARNING

Students in this course have the opportunity to seek a Work Integrated Learning placement with an industry partner equivalent to one semester of fulltime study. Such placements are available to students who have:

Successfully completed any prerequisite units,

Successfully completed at least two thirds of the requirements towards the degree and,

Have a Weighted Average Mark (WAM) of 65% or higher across their course, or

Have a WAM of 70% or higher for the two semesters preceding their application.

Students who meet these criteria and who wish to participate in Work Integrated Learning must apply in writing to their Course Coordinator by the end of the first year of the course (or PRIOR to enrolling in Project Preparation). Students should seek the advice of the Course Coordinator as to the appropriateness of pursuing the work placement option within their course structure and also as to their eligibility to be considered. Selection will be based on academic performance, the application and a formal interview process.

Successful applicants for work placement must enroll in and complete the requirements for the unit Work Experience Project (in place of Project Preparation, Project 1 and Project 2). This is a 60 credit point unit and represents a full semester’s study load. Students are advised NOT to enroll in any additional units while taking the Work Experience Project unit. Students should also note that failure to successfully complete Work Experience Project could necessitate completing Project Preparation/Project 1/Project 2 instead, which could add two extra semesters to the course duration.
]]>

</course_desc>
</course>
</courses>
```

I would like the output to retain its orginal formatting of the CDATA so just like you see in the course_desc element. It is a description section that is just copy/pasted in so it should look like whatever is pasted in. In XSLT I have tried value-of and copy-of but I just get errors as it won't read out the CDATA.

Have I got the CDATA stored wrong in the XML or can't you use value-of/copy-of to display it?

Thanks.

EDITED with xslt file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Course information</h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course" />

</body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="course">
    <strong>Course: <xsl:text> </xsl:text></strong> <xsl:value-of select="text()" /><br />  
<strong>Coordinator Name: <xsl:text> </xsl:text></strong><xsl:value-of select="course_coordinator/fname"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="course_coordinator/sname"/><br /><br />

 <xsl:variable name="link" select="course_coordinator/image" />
    <xsl:variable name="cname" select="course_corrdinator/image" />
              <img src="{$link}" alt="{$cname}"/><br /><br />


<!-- <xsl:vaule-of select="course_desc"/> among some alternatives I tried here -->

   <strong>Elective List: <xsl:text> </xsl:text></strong>
   <xsl:for-each select="electives/elective">

   <li><a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="elective_link" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="elective_code" /></a><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="elective_title" /></li>

   <br />
   </xsl:for-each>
       <br />

<xsl:apply-templates select="year" />

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="year">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="semester" />
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="semester">
    <strong>Year: <xsl:text> </xsl:text></strong><xsl:value-of select="../@ynum"/><br />
    <strong>Semester: <xsl:text> </xsl:text></strong><xsl:value-of select="@snum"/><br />
    <table border="0">

        <tr bgcolor="#B0C4DE">

            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Credit Points</th>

        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="units/unit" />
    </table>
<br/><br/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="unit">
    <tr>
        <td><a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="unit_link" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="unit_code" /></a></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="unit_title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="cp"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show the XSLT you are actually using in this case, along with the actual error messages you are getting? Thank you!

Comment: so the output will look like the text in `course_desc` without `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`

Comment: So after that with course template I would have something like 

<xsl:value-of select="course_desc"/>
or <xsl:value-of select="course_desc" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

But i think the error lies in how I have stored the CDATA itself as even if there is no xslt it fails to load while the <![CDATA[ ]]> is in the xml.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Yeah I am after an output in XSLT that will show what is inside <course_desc><![CDATA[ ... ]]></course_desc> and for it to be the same eg: not change any of the formatting of what is inside course_desc to just display it "as is".

Someone said you can use CDATA for this which is what I am trying to do but of there is a better approach please let me know :).

Comment: If you want to keep newlines and spacing in HTML, use a `<pre>` element.

Comment: @Tomalak Okay could you do something like <pre><xsl:value-of select="course_desc"/></pre>  in the XSLT and the XML "course_desc" is still the where it draws it from?

Comment: Basically, yes. Remember that `<pre>` does also mean "no line-breaks or reflow of content". Everything will appear exactly as in the input XML, long lines will extend beyond the width of the screen.

Comment: "Someone said you can use CDATA for this" - that person has mis-understood.  The purpose of CDATA is to make the parser treat as literals characters like `&` and `<` that would normally represent markup.  As far as an XML parser is concerned "`<![CDATA[this & that]]>`" is exactly the same as "`this &amp; that`".

Comment: If you're producing HTML output and you want the blank lines to be treated as paragraph breaks then you will need to split up the text at blank lines and render each chunk as a separate `p` element or similar.